# Looking for bash command to recursively find and copy only files from one dir hierarchy to another

Tags: command-line, bash

Is it possible to run a command using bash that will replace all the files in one directory structure with all the files in another. For example, if I have these two directory structures:

```
dest
dest/A
dest/A/B
dest/A/B/file-1
dest/A/B/file-2
dest/A/B/file-3
dest/A/B/C
dest/A/B/C/file-4
dest/A/B/C/file-5

patch/
patch/A
patch/A/B
patch/A/B/file-2
patch/A/B/C
patch/A/B/C/file-6
```

...then can I run some sort of find/copy/xargs/sed piped command that will copy each **file** under the patch directory to its corresponding location in the dest directory? If I just `cp -r patch/A/B dest/A/B` then I'll loose the files `dest/A/B/file-1` and `dest/A/B/file-3` etc.

**Edit:**

I have tried running commands myself e.g. `find -type f | xargs -I {} cp {} ...` , but I'm not very experienced with shell commands and nothing has worked (the `...` at the end of the command has mostly been experiments with sed to transform the filepath by replacing the `./` with `dest/`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use rsync to achieve this; `rsync -Aax /input/directory/path /output/directory/path`
(note that the flags will preserve owner,group and security privileges).

I should add that your statement, from which I believe your entire problem arises, "If I just `cp -r patch/A/B dest/A/B` then I'll loose the files `dest/A/B/file-1` and `dest/A/B/file-3` etc" is not accurate; you could also simply run `cp -r patch/A dest/A/` and achieve what you seem to be looking for (no already existing files will be removed)

Comment: This is a great idea. I don't use rsync normally, but I always thought of it as just an alternative to scp

Comment: It's a fantastic utility, certainly worth your while. Please also see my added comment having just edited my post.

Comment: You're right, of course, about the `cp -r patch/A/* ...`. I don't understand why that works with the file glob though. What's happening that's different compared with `cp -r patch/A dest/A`. Is the wildcard interpreted as "recurse through each sub-directory but only copy files"?

Comment: No - that's actually a bad habit of mine. You can equally execute `cp -r patch/A dest/` with the same results (just remember to add that trailing slash to the destination to denote its status as a directory). Edited to 'best practices' method above.